# Reduce processing time using OpenMP and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, openmp

I am very much new to OpenMP and OpenCV. I am trying to reduce the time for differencing two images using OpenCV and OpenMP. But the time taken in parallel for loop using OpenMP is more than in sequential for loop.Kindly Suggest what can be done.

My code is

```
int main () 
{

omp_set_num_threads(4);
double omp_time1,omp_time2;

cv::Mat image_1= cv::imread("1.png");   
cv::Mat image_2=cv::imread("2.png");


vector<cv::Mat> rgb_planes_1;
cv::split( image_1, rgb_planes_1 );
vector<cv::Mat> rgb_planes_2;
cv::split( image_2, rgb_planes_2 );

cv::Mat sub_rgb_0[3];

#ifdef _OPENMP
omp_time1 = omp_get_wtime();
#endif

#pragma omp parallel private(tid)
  {
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  if (tid == 0)
    {
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
    }
  printf("Thread %d starting...\n",tid);
  #pragma omp for schedule(static) 
  for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {

        absdiff(rgb_planes_1[i],rgb_planes_2[i],sub_rgb_0[i]);

     }
   }
#ifdef _OPENMP
omp_time2 = omp_get_wtime();
#endif

 printf("Parallel::%f seconds.\n", omp_time2 - omptime1);
}
```

It takes 
Parallel:: 0.006757 seconds.

When I tried the same without the OpenMP segment the CPU clock gives
0.00200 seconds.

Comment: I don't think you need `schedule(static)` for just 3 for loops. See if gets faster by avoiding that.

Comment: You're only running your benchmark once, and it's a very, very small test. The time is probably being dominated by the OpenMP initialization time, which will only affect the first run. I suggest two experiments: try running the test 10 times, instead of just once, and try a (much) larger image.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the infos Alex and pburka gave, that your sceduling isn't necessarily optimal for such a low number of loops and timing just one round cannot give a reliable measurement, keep in mind that OpenCV is highly optimized and uses itself TBB and SMID optimization. So you probably won't get any better than calling absdiff once with a 3-channel Mat.